# D3.js: how to append elements when data is already bound?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having a problem with [D3 joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/). I have created some circles on a bubble graph. When the user clicks on a 'show as map' button, I want to transform the circles onto a map, then  add a label to each one.

Currently the click handler moves the circles OK, then gives me a JavaScript error rather than adding the labels: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object SVGCircleElement]... has no method 'append'`. I know this is because my join syntax is incorrect, but how can I fix it?

All the examples I can find of adding new D3 elements are for cases where you're binding new data - not when you already have existing elements with data already bound.

This is my code for creating the circles:

```
  var circle = g.selectAll('.city')
     .data(data).enter()
     .append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'city')
    .attr('r', rfunc).attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return rdist(d['dist']);
    }).attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "rotate(" + d.radial_pos + " 0 0)";
    });
```

And this is my click handler:

```
d3.select("#layout_geo").on("click", function() {
    // Move the circles - this works OK. 
    var circles = d3.selectAll(".city")
    .transition()
    .duration(1300)
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
       return merc([d['lon'], d['lat']])[0] - 350;
    }).attr('cy', function(d) {
      return merc([d['lon'], d['lat']])[1] - 280;
    });
    // How to add text to each circle?
    circles.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'background')
      .text(function(d) {
         console.log(d.name + ', ' + d.city);
          return d.name + ', ' + d.city;
      })
      .attr('cx', function() {
        return ???;
      }).attr('cy', function() {
        return ???;
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the `circles` is not a normal selection but a [transition](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions). They have a convenient `remove()` function to allow for removal of items, but not `append` for adding more elements.

Another problem is that appending `<text>` elements *inside* a `<circle>` attribute is not correct SVG. In this case, you need to put the `<text>` and the `<circle>` inside a `g` element [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/VbUza/). The corresponding change in the code would be:

```
d3.select("#layout_geo").on("click", function() {
    // Assign the seleciton to circles
    var circleG = d3.selectAll(".city");

    circleG.transition()
      .duration(1300)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(-100, -50)'); // Ignoring the rotation.

    // And append text to the selection
    circleG.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'background')
      .attr('dx', '1em')
      .text(function(d) {
          console.log(d.name + ', ' + d.city);
          return d.name + ', ' + d.city;
      });
  });
```

Note that the rotation is lost on the `<circle>` element while changing the `transform` attribute. It can be preserved by [using two nested g elements with rotation on the outer one.](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, as it stands that code is no longer producing an error, but it also isn't appending anything to the DOM. It's quite strange, because it's writing to the console, but the elements are simply not appearing in the DOM.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, my bad. Actually, adding a `<text>` element _inside_ a `<circle>` element will have no effect, and I think does not conform to the SVG standard. In that case, you need to put the `<text>` and the `<circle>` inside a `g` element [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/VbUza/). If that is what you are looking for, I will update the answer. Note that the `rotation` is lost on the `<circle> element, but that can be achieved by using [two nested g elements with rotation on the outer one](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute).

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you! Really helped me understand how groups work in SVG.